# How to create an Excel file download link

Tags: html, excel, hyperlink

How can I create a download link for my existing Excel file?

```html
<a href='/path/to/excel/file.xls' download="file.xls">Download </a>
```

I tried this and it did not allow me to download the file.
Do I need to copy my Excel file to Visual Studio?

Comment: Is your server set up with a MIME type for `.xls` files? Which server software are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't work as a link, you can also try it as a button :

```
<form>
<input type="button" value="Download" onClick="window.location.href='/path/to/excel/file.xls'">
</form>
```

Comment: well try this for a link : <a href='/path/to/excel/file.xls' target="_blank">Download file</a>